# Organizing strings in recursive functions - python

Tags: python, string, recursion

I'm trying to split and organize a string in a single function, my goal is to seperate lowercase and uppercase characters and then return a new string essentially like so:

```
    "lowercasestring" + " " + "uppercasestring".
```

Importantly all characters must return in the order they were recieved but split up.
My problem is that i have to do this recursively in a single function(for educational purposes) and i struggle to understand how this is doable without an external function calling the recursive and then modifying the string.

```
    def split_rec(string):
        if string == '':                                                     
            return "-"                                                     #used to seperate late
        elif str.islower(string[0]) or string[0] == "_" or string[0] == ".": #case1
            return string[0] + split_rec(string[1:])
        elif str.isupper(string[0]) or string[0] == " " or string[0] == "|": #case2
            return split_rec(string[1:]) + string[0]
        else:                                                                #discard other
            return split_rec(string[1:])

    def call_split_rec(string):  
    ##Essentially i want to integrate the functionality of this whole function into the recursion
        mystring = split_rec(string)
        left, right = mystring.split("-")
        switch_right = right[::1]
        print(left + " " + switchright)
```

The recursion alone would return:

```
    "lowerUPPERcaseCASE" -> "lowercase" + "ESACREPPU"
```

My best attempt at solving this in a single function was to make case2:

```
    elif str.isupper(string[-1]) or string[-1] == " " or string[-1] == "|": #case2
        return split_rec(string[:-1]) + string[-1]
```

So that the uppercase letters would be added with last letter first, in order to correctly print the string. The issue here is that i obviously just get stuck when the first character is uppercase and the last one is lowercase.

I've spent alot of time trying to figure out a good solution to this, but im unable and there's no help for me to be found. I hope the question is not too stupid - if so feel free to remove it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do this recursively, but I guess you don't have a choice here. ;)

The simple way to do this in one function is to use a couple of extra arguments to act as temporary storage for the lower and upper case chars.

```
def split_rec(s, lo='', up=''):
    ''' Recursively split s into lower and upper case parts '''
    # Handle the base case: s is the empty string
    if not s: 
        return lo + ' ' + up

    #Otherwise, append the leading char of s 
    # to the appropriate destination...
    c = s[0]
    if c.islower():
        lo += c
    else:
        up += c
        # ... and recurse
    return split_rec(s[1:], lo, up)

# Test

print(split_rec("lowerUPPERcaseCASE"))
```

**output**

```
lowercase UPPERCASE
```

---

I have a couple of comments about your code.

It's not a great idea to use `string` as a variable name, since that's the name of a standard module. It won't hurt anything, unless you want to import that module, but it's still potentially confusing to people reading your code. The `string` module doesn't get a lot of use these days, but in the early versions of Python the standard string functions lived there. But then the `str` type inherited those functions as methods, making the old `string` functions obsolete.

And on that note, you generally should call those `str` methods as methods, rather than as functions. So *don't* do:

```
str.islower(s[0])
```

instead, do

```
s[0].islower()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Simply adding additional arguments to the recursive function was the kind of simple solution i was overlooking. Your comments about my code are also greatly appreciated, there are alot of smaller things like that im still missing.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use [`sorted`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) with a custom key:

```
>>> ''.join(sorted("lowerUPPERcaseCASE" + " ", key=str.isupper))
'lowercase UPPERCASE'
```

There's really no reason to use any recursive function here. If it's for educational purpose, you could try to find a problem for which it's actually a good idea to write a recursive function (fibonacci, tree parsing, merge sort, ...).

As mentioned by @PM2Ring in the comments, this sort works fine here because Python `sorted` is [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts): when sorting by case, letters with the same case stay at the same place relative to one another.

Comment: Sure, but that's not recursive.

Comment: @PM2Ring: There's 0 reason to write a recursive function here. The correct answer to "How do I cut a woodenboard in two with a hammer?" is "Use a saw", not "Apply more pressure with the hammer".

Comment: Yes even i understand this problem is very poorly fit for a recursive solution, i could solve the problem easily using iteration. The solution you give looks very nice for when i actually do need to be efficient, thanks. But like i said the problem was moreso about my poor understanding of how to make recursion work in this instance than it was about solving the actual problem.

Comment: There's 1 reason to use recursion: that's what the OP stated in the question. ;) Generally that means they're doing homework, and they _have_ to use recursion because that's what they're currently studying. But of course it's also possible that the OP is self-studying, and not being forced to use recursion by their teacher. I fully agree that normally one should only use recursion in Python when it's appropriate for the problem domain (like dealing with a recursive data structure); OTOH, there's no harm in learning how to use recursion in cases where it's not the natural approach.

Comment: @cmnty BTW, Eric's solution works because Python's sort function, [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), is _stable_, so you can perform sorts in multiple stages and each stage won't unduly disturb the results of the previous stages.

Comment: Ok. Let's delete those comments to avoid confusing future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Another take with recursive helper functions

```
def f(s):
    def lower(s):
        if not s:
            return ''
        c = s[0] if s[0].islower() else ''
        return c + lower(s[1:])
    def upper(s):
        if not s:
            return ''
        c = s[0] if s[0].isupper() else ''
        return c + upper(s[1:])
    return lower(s) + ' ' + upper(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with only the string as parameter:

```
def split_rec(s):
    if not '|' in s:
        s = s + '|'

    if s.startswith('|'):                                                     
            return s.replace('|', ' ')

    elif s[0].islower():
        return s[0] + split_rec(s[1:])

    elif s[0].isupper():
        # we move the uppercase first letter to the end
        s = s[1:] +  s[0]
        return split_rec(s)
    else:                                                                
            return split_rec(s[1:])

split_rec('aAbBCD')
# 'ab ABCD'
```

The idea is:

- We add a marker at the end (I chose `|`)
- If the first char is lowercase, we return it + the organized rest
- If it is uppercase, we move it to the end, and reorganize the whole string
- We stop once we reach the marker: the current string is the marker followed by the organized uppercase letters. We replace the marker by a space and return it.